# Getting error "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'as'"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near keyword 'as'

but I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
SELECT 
    tef.TicketEntryId, tef.FieldName,
    CASE 
       WHEN TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, tef.FieldValue) IS NOT NULL 
          THEN lli.Name 
          ELSE 
             CASE 
                WHEN tef.FieldDataType = 'BOOL' 
                   THEN CAST(tef.FieldValue AS BIT)
                   ELSE tef.FieldValue 
             END AS FieldValue
FROM 
    TicketEntry.TicketExtendedField tef
LEFT JOIN 
    RefList.LookupListItem lli ON CAST(lli.LookupListItemId AS VARCHAR(36)) = tef.FieldValue
WHERE 
    tef.TicketEntryId = 'bc18a2e9-441f-433f-bd1f-ddb646758584'
```

The line that is throwing the error is `ELSE tef.FieldValue END as FieldValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ended one `CASE` statement and forgot to end the other one.

Change this line:

```
ELSE tef.FieldValue END AS FieldValue
```

to

```
ELSE tef.FieldValue END END AS FieldValue
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had been staring at that statement for a while.  It was written by one of my co-workers.  Sometimes all you need some time is another set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, there is no reason for two case *expressions*:

```
SELECT tef.TicketEntryId, tef.FieldName,
       (CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, tef.FieldValue) IS NOT NULL 
             THEN lli.Name 
             WHEN tef.FieldDataType = 'BOOL' 
             THEN CAST(tef.FieldValue AS BIT)
             ELSE tef.FieldValue
        END) as FieldValue
FROM TicketEntry.TicketExtendedField tef LEFT JOIN
     RefList.LookupListItem lli
     ON CAST(lli.LookupListItemId AS VARCHAR(36)) = tef.FieldValue
WHERE tef.TicketEntryId = 'bc18a2e9-441f-433f-bd1f-ddb646758584';
```

That said, this `case` or your version has a typing problem.  The `case` expression returns a single value, with a single type.  Why are you casting the value as a bit?  Presumably the intended return type of the `case` is a `varchar()`, so it will never return a `bit` value.  However, the attempted conversion is likely to cause an error.

Comment: I didn't write the code, but it is being cast to a bit because it is bool field and needs to be a bool field and not a string to work with checkbox in a DevExpress report. It is a lot to explain.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff . . . I'm just saying that the result of the `case` is a bit (because of the `cast()`), and this could lead to problems.